# How to improve performance for group aggregation in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a collection with **17 millions** of documents with around 40 fields inside. I am grouping it by "State" and I want to have the average for latitude, longitude and count of document in each state.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [{$group:
    {_id:"$State", 
      avgLat: {$avg: "$Latitude"},
      avgLon:{$avg: "$Longitude"},
      count: {$sum:1}}
    }
  ])
```

That query takes around **40 seconds**.
I am missing anything? The worst case scenario is that there won't be any filter upon the data, so no `$match` pipeline stage.
I've read that there is cap for aggregation with 100MB of ram. Is it possible that's the reason for slow computation of this query?
The version of mongoDB is: 6.0.2

I have added separate indexes for Latitude, Longitude and state, but that did not improved anything.
What can I change, maybe some configuration?
I am trying to have the time decreased to below 3 seconds, it is supposed to be in web API.

Comment: It may improve if you put `{$sort: {State: 1}}` in front of `$group`.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to get it down to 3 seconds, you'll need to preprocess this and then serve the stale data.

you could preprocess this every minute if it runs in 40secs so worse case scenario is 59 secs staleness which is already caused by the current query.

Comment: Recent MongoDB release introduced [Slot-Based Query Execution Engine Pipeline Optimizations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#sbe-title-pipeline-optimizations), it may become better in future. However, you should not use it yet, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-70395

Comment: Sharded cluster would be an option, but it might be an overkill. If you require less than 3 seconds, then you need to pre-process the data and store the result.

Comment: Just see, you are already using version 6.0. In this case try to [set parameter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#setparameter-option) `internalQueryForceClassicEngine: true`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks. Additional question:  if I would add a $match on that data, then I would need to preprocess again for any $match variant?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Comment: Regarding the RAM cap: Yes, there is a limit of 100 MB. If the data is bigger then data is spilled to disk. In earlier versions you had to set option `{allowDiskUse: true}` for this, in version 6.0 this is now the default.